# Unexpected JDWP Error:103 while using retrofit with rxjava to access a dynamic url

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have tried the solutions mentioned already in stackoverflow and my code is as follows

```java
    (new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASEURL+barcodevalue+"/")                
            .build()
    )
    .create(ApiSets.class)
    .searchTweets(Constants.BASEURL+barcodevalue+"/");
```

and I am getting `Unexpected JDWP Error:103`

Comment: What is your environment (versions, etc.)? If this is something transient, you could apply `retry(Predicate)` which checks for this particular exception and retries the call.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any update on this ?